# Can you solder the tab on a FQP30N06 MOSFET to the GND plane on a PCB?

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, heatsink

I've got a FET that I want to be laid down on my first PCB. Can I solder the tab to a pad attached to the GND plane as someone on reddit suggested?

Comment: If you have read something somewhere on the web, and you think it's relevant to the question, then you should post the link.

Comment: Maybe but we need your circuit.  if the Drain is not connected to GND then No.

Comment: No, it's not connected to GND. It's connected to my load and source is GND. @NickAlexeev I would but it was an offhand reddit comment. Someone just said they'd solder it down :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As peufeu mentioned you can only do this if the drain (the tab is connected to the middle pin, which is the drain in the case of the FQP30N06) is supposed to be tied to ground. Usually you want to keep the tab isolated as its main purpose is to mate to a heat sink. What I recommend doing is create a copper pour on your PCB that either has no net, or has the same net that the drain is supposed to connect to. This pour could act as a built-in PCB heatsink. Just keep it isolated from surrounding components, tracks, and pours.

Comment: Is this a common thing, soldering the tab down like this? If there's a good reason to create that separate pour I will, but it's an [inconvenient spot](https://imgur.com/anb9yr3) because I'd have to move some shielding vias and a trace that is connected to my GND pour. Guess I could just create a tiny pad to solder one corner to...

Comment: Usually this method is used for surface mount packages, such as the DPAK. However, I do often see it done for TO-220s as well. In your case, if you're not concerned about the transistor heating up, you could lay down a mica or sil-pad insulator between the transistor and the board to keep it isolated from the existing ground pour.

Answer (score 3):

The tab is usually the drain (check datasheet) so if your schematic connects the drain to GND then yes. Otherwise, no.